# How to multiply the results of two different queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: Employee, BillingRates, and WorkHours.

```
Employees
------------------------------
EmpID | name | titleID | level  

BillingRates
----------------------
titleID | level | rate

WorkHours
-------------------
EmpID | HoursWorked
```

This query gives me the names and rate for each employee:

```
select 
    firstname, lastname, rate
from employees 
left join billingrates
    on employees.TitleID = BillingRates.TitleID
    and employees.Level = BillingRates.Level
```

This gives me the EmpID and total hours worked by that employee:

```
select 
    employees.EmpID, sum(workhours.hoursworked) as TotalHours
from employees 
inner join workhours
    on employees.empid = WorkHours.EmpID
where 
    WH_Month = 4
group by 
    LastName, firstname, employees.EmpID
```

I need to multiply the rate output by the total hours worked by that employee.
Would someone be able to assist with writing a query that generates that output?

Comment: just join `billingrates` to the second query as well, and multiply the sum by `min(rate)`. or `max(rate)`. or even just `rate` (if this is mysql and not sql-server; please pick one)

Comment: You have the tags `mysql`, `sql-server` and `oracle`.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, it's SQL Server. I'm new to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in SQL server

```
select employees.EmpID, sum(workhours.hoursworked) as 'TotalHours',
       firstname, lastname, 
       ISNULL(sum(workhours.hoursworked),0) * ISNULL(min(rate),0) AS 'TotalRate'
from employees inner join workhours
on employees.empid = WorkHours.EmpID
LEFT JOIN BillingRates ON employees.titleid=billingrates.titleid
AND employees.level = billingrates.level
where WH_Month = 4
group by LastName, firstname, employees.EmpID
```

Comment: That's great Ala. That's exactly what I needed. I was not familiar with ISNULL(SUM(...)